# Sprite Kit - Low Resolution Texture on Retina when using textureFromNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

For my game I am trying to create custom textures from two other textures. This is to allow for a varietly of colours, etc in my sprites.

To do this, I'm creating a sprite by adding both textures together, then applying this to a new SKTexture by using

```
SKTexture *texture = [self.view textureFromNode:newSprite];
```

This works great on the whole and I get a nice custom texture. Except when trying my game on Retina devices, where the texture is the correct size on the screen, but clearly a lower resolution.

The textures are all there and properly named so I don't believe that that is an issue.

Has anyone encountered this, or know how I can create the proper @2x texture?

Comment: you could also use the color property and/or compose a sprite of multiple sprites overlaying the main sprite, I don't see why you would need to create a new texture for that

Comment: Well the parts that I'm making the textures from can't just be colored. They're specific designs that our artist has made up. So similar to the way Jetpack Joyride must combine it's different jetpacks and different outfits.

Comment: Still, assuming that a jetpack consists of multiple, uniquely designed parts, you can create a sprite node for each part and combine them in a single SKNode, and perhaps colorize each individual part as needed and you'd get the same effect without needing to have this as a separate texture. Moreso you can then animate the individual parts, for example to make them come apart when crashing or to individually colorize them to show damage.

Comment: I've noticed this as well. This is a real problem for people who are using textureFromNode to blit node hierarchies to textures that haven't been added to the scene, for particle effects etc. You can use drawViewHierarchyInRect on the SKView, but this requires the node hierarchies to already have been drawn. I don't know if it is a bug, or something to do with the size and then placement of the texture being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally (accidentally) figured out how to fix this. The node which you are creating a texture from has to be added to the scene. Otherwise you will get a non-retina size for your texture.

It's not ideal as it would be nice to create textures without having to add them onto the screen.

Comment: Stuart, could you provide a sample illustrating what you did? I tried your suggestion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186397/how-to-have-texturefromnode-produce-texture-for-retina-display but the texture obtained is still low-resolution.  Any tips what am I missing?

Comment: It is not sufficient to add the source node the the scene.  Another condition is that `textureFromNode` is called from inside the `update:` function or (not tested) after `update:` has been called at least once.  Solutions to the issue of having to add the source node to the scene: 1. remove the node after you called `textureFromNode`; it will never be rendered this way; 2. position the source node off-screen (scene.anchorPoint+{1024, 768}+a bit more); off-screen nodes do consume some resources but they are not sent to the GPU and are definitely not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered another way of improving the fidelity of textures created from ShapeNodes, not quite related to this question - but useful intel.

Create your shape at x2 its size and width. 
Create all the fonts and other shapes at the same oversized ratio. 
Make sure your positioning is relative to this overall size, (e.g. don't use absolute sizes, use relative sizes to the container.)

When you create the texture as a sprite it'll be huge - but then apply

```
sprite.scale = 0.5; // if you were using 2x
```

I've found this makes it look much higher resolution, no graininess, no fuzziness on fonts, sharp corners.

I also used `tex.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;`

Thus: it doesn't have to be added to the scene and then removed.